# how can i create dyanmic chat.js using php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

the thing is, I don't understand how I can pass the value from the url to the php itself dynamically. I think I need to retrieve mysql value from my database and assign it to some variable, is that correct? But how can I connect it to the URL? and pass to the javasript for chart.js .

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get the data as an array and pass it into the labels and data, for example:

```
*Draw Graph*/
        var barChartData = {
            labels : sortedLabels,
            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data :sortedCounts
                }
            ]

        }
```

So labels: sortedLabels and data: sortedCounts was a javascript object which I split into an two arrays to use for Chart.js.

Comment: I don't even understand the question. How do you know what he's expection for an answer?

Comment: English is not everyones first language and some of us can articulate ourselves better than others. Besides that, you can derive that the user want to add dynamic content with PHP from MySQL to the chart.js javascript plugin.

Comment: thank you siegfried Grimbeek